# Solution verification of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{1/n}-e^{-1/n}-2/n}{1/n-\sin{(1/n)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

If I have to consider the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{1/n}-e^{-1/n}-2/n}{1/n-\sin{(1/n)}}$$
I have thought to apply the asymptotic criterion and so:
$$1)\,\, e^{1/n}=1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{6n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})$$
$$2)\,\, e^{-1/n}=1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{6n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})$$
$$3)\,\, \sin{(1/n)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{3!\cdot n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^4})$$
From which I have:
$$\frac{e^{1/n}-e^{-1/n}-2/n}{1/n-\sin{(1/n)}}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{6n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})-(1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{6n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^3}))-2/n}{1/n-(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{3!\cdot n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^4}))}=\frac{\frac{1}{3 n^3}+o(1/n^3)}{\frac{1}{6 n^3}+o(1/n^4)}\sim 2$$
Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2$ diverges than the original series diverges from asymptotic test.

Is my work right?

Comment: Looks correct to me

Comment: @Alessandro So every time a term is asymptotic to a constant then the series diverges?

Comment: @Sisi Yes, this suffices.